# Please help in finding the XPath:

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I've the below snippet, I need to find the Xpath to click on "Option1"

The Problem here is below two divisions are dynamically displayed based on the browser size or Screen Resolution

```
<div class="wrap">
    <aside id="side-anchor-links">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a class="anchor-active">Option1</a></li>
            <li"><a class="">Option2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <main class="content">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="scroller">
                <div id="top-anchor-links" class="scroll-me">
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a class="">Option1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="">Option2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

Thanks is Advance.

My Trails:
`xpath = //aside[@id="side-anchor-links"]/ul/li[text()="Option1"]` //This option will work only when the options are displayed in the side view
`xpath = //li[text()="Option1"]` //This option will retrieve two occurances

Note: Always `class="anchor-active"` is associated with option1 in Side View until we click on any option from any division

Comment: Could you be more precise, why //li[text()="Option1"] does not resolve your issue, do you use find elementS method?

Comment: Can you check if there is any frame or something among the predecessor nodes ??

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below xpath :

```
//div[@class='wrap']/aside[@id="side-anchor-links"]/ul/li[1]
```

Comment: This will not work when the options are displayed in "top-anchor-links" division. 
I mean when I reduce the Browser Size all the options, which are in "top-anchor-links", are displayed on the web page. In that case this xpath will not work...

Comment: I need an Xpath which will work in either of the cases OR else is there any mechanism to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

So, I believe you need to click at one element, and if it is not present - on another.

And if plain `//li[text()='Option1']` does not suite you well, try this:

```
//*[@id='side-anchor-links' or @id='top-anchor-links']//li/a
```

Better customize your `//li/a` part, however

Comment: `//*[@id='side-anchor-links' or @id='top-anchor-links']//li/a` will also not work as it is satisfying both the options

Any function can we develop in order overcome this situation? Please suggest me if any...

Comment: I suggest that you overcome this programatically, rather than on xpath level, so if you need to click a button, you search for first one, if it is not present - for second with it's own xpath. Also, it is unclear from your question, which button should be clicked with most priority. Specified XPath will first match button in `aside` , if there is no - will match in `main`. I do not see any problem with matching both, unless you want to check there is only ONE button present.